# Video calls in Ionic application are not working on devices (but are working in the browser)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, video, hybrid-mobile-app, amazon-chime

We are developing an Ionic application and we want to use Amazon chime to organize video calls between two clients. SDK is connected, permission to use the camera is received, there are no errors in the console, but after the start of the call, the video is not transmitted (a black screen is visible in the preview).
Although, if we run the same code in a browser - everything works and even the browser video (and sound) is displayed on the device. Apparently the problem is in capturing video from the video camera on the device. Choosing another device from the list did not help (front or back camera). We tried on Android and IOS.
Any solutions to this problem, examples or links would be appreciated.